# Trying to change UI control property from different thread using . InvokeRequired

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What am I doing wrong here?

my plan is to change the label text property from a different thread without getting the "Cross-thread operation not valid" exception.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ChangeTime));
        thread1.Start();
    }

    delegate void SetTimeDelegate();

    private void ChangeTime()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (lbl1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTimeDelegate setTime = new SetTimeDelegate(ChangeTime);
                lbl1.Invoke(setTime);


            }
            else
            {
                lbl1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't invoking. Honestly, I can't tell what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I'm trying to change the text from a label from the form to current datetime called from a new thread

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update a UI control from a different thread you need to call the `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke` method. You can use the specific control's methods or the form's.

Your original code has infinite recursion. You are Invoking correctly except your delegate is calling the same method. Create a separate method for updating the label with the time and have the delegate cll that new method.

```
private bool _IsShuttingDown = false;

private void ChangeTime()
{
   while (!_IsShuttingDown)
   {
      if (lbl1.InvokeRequired)
      {
         SetTimeDelegate setTime = new SetTimeDelegate(UpdateTimeLabel);
         lbl1.Invoke(setTime);
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
      else
      {
         UpdateTimeLabel();
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
   }
}

private void UpdateTimeLabel()
{
   lbl1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
}

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
   _IsShuttingDown = true;
   base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

I also added a field on the form to exit the loop when the form is closing or else weird things happen.

My original code:

```
if (lbl1.InvokeRequired)
{
    lbl1.Invoke((Action)(() => lbl1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I didn't fully understand this cast to Action

Comment: @EdwinSnts I changed the code to better fit your original code. All cast to Action does is make it act like a Delegate.

Comment: this is very helpful, i used to declare a delegate to and call it whenever i need to update a control from a different thread, but that is also useful if you are trying to update more than one control